# Error compiling a Qt program containing WebView

Tags: qt5, qwebview

I created a new Qt5 project. All i do is drag a QWebView into my MainWindowUI. It gives me these errors:

`error: undefined reference to`*imp*__ZN8QWebViewC1EP7QWidget'`

and

`error: undefined reference to`*imp*__ZN8QWebView6setUrlERK4QUrl`

I havent even written a single line of code! Is something wrong with QtDesigner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "webkit"( till  Qt 4.7.4) or webkitwidgets(Qt5) on pro file. like "QT       += core gui webkit", then clean and build.

Comment: it didnt work .
my .pro's first line : 
QT += core gui webkit

Comment: did you perform Clean the project then build the project?.

Comment: ok i got it ! the actuall module name was " webkitwidgets "
its working now ! but i didnt thought of the pro file at all . so thanks for that :)

Comment: That is great. Ohh you are using Qt5 that is why webkitwidgets, webkit is gone.